# σ-algebra generated by X with restrictions on X(ω)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Can you please help me solve this problem? I understand the concept of a σ-algebra generated by any given collection of subsets of a given set. However, when the question imposes X(ωi)=constant where i=1,...,n defined in a sample space given by Ω := {ω1,ω2,...,ωn} I don't know how to write the σ-algebra generated by X.

Here is a concrete example of what I'm trying to ask:

Let X be a random variable defined on a sample space Ω. Compute σ(X), that is the σ-algebra generated by X, when Ω := {ω1,ω2,ω3} and X(ω1) = 0, X(ω2) = 1 and X(ω3) = 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't know what is meant by "sigma-algebra generated by a random variable", is that right?

Comment: I thought I understood it, but maybe I didn't!

Comment: No issues , take your time in understanding it! Kindly use MathJax for your next posts, then you will get more attention on your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sigma algebra genertated by $X$ in your last example is the power set. This sigma algbera contains $\{\omega_1\}=\{X=0\}, \{\omega_2\}=\{X=1\}$ and $\{\omega_3\}=\{X=2\}$ so it contains all subsets of $\Omega$.

In general $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(A):A \, \text  {Borel in }  \, \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: What if X(ω1) = X(ω2) = X(ω3) = 1 for the same exact sample space?

Comment: @MiguelFarinha In that case $\sigma(X)$ contains only two sets, the empty set and $\Omega$.

Comment: I don't understand why that happens! I'm sorry could you please explain?

Comment: @MiguelFarinha You have consider sets of the type $X^{-1}(A)$. If $X$ has same value at all points then either each $\omega_i$ is in $X^{-1}(A)$ or none of them is. So $X^{-1}(A)$ is either empty or the whole space.

Comment: @MiguelFarinha In that case $A$ may contain one, two or   all three of the numbers $0,1,2$ . By considering the case where $A$ contains exactly one of these numbers we see that $\{\omegw_i\} \in \sigma (X)$ for every $i$.

Comment: In your first answer when you say {ω1}={X=0} does this mean that {ω1} ⊂ σ(X) and if {ω2}={X=1} then {ω2} ⊂ σ(X) and so on? Because it is assigned different real number for each of the ωi's? The we just have to fulfill the requeriments for it to be a sigma algbera?

Comment: @MiguelFarinha Rigth that is the argument.

Comment: Then if X(ω1) = 0, X(ω2) = 0 and X(ω3) = 1 this means that σ(X)={Ω,∅,{w1,w2},{w3}}. Is this correct? Then {ω1,ω2}={X=0} and {ω3}={X=1} so {w1,w2} ⊂ σ(X) and {w3} ⊂ σ(X)? And the σ(X) is the one I wrote in the first line?

Comment: @MiguelFarinha Yes,and I think you go the complete idea now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!